# Bootstrap slider - get value and show it in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented bootstrap and jquery and bootstrap jquery (https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider). I am using example 6 (http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/).
I want to get that value and show it in a div (so later I can create an if with that value), but I cannot get it to show.
This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 39px; padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;>
    <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="10000" data-slider-max="100000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="90000"/>
    <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Maksimalna cena: <span id="ex6SliderVal">90000</span></span> din.
</div>
<div id ="ivancar"> test </div>
```

And this is my JavaScript (jQuery) code:

```
var slider = new Slider("#slider1");
   slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
   console.log(slider.getValue() );
   var div = slider.getValue();
});
document.getElementById("ivancar").innerHTML = div;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have placed the logic of updating your `div` outside the `slide` event. Place it within the slide event.

```
 slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
   console.log(slider.getValue() );
   var div = slideEvt.value; // this is what the plugin says
   $("#ivancar").html(div); // <== update logic must be here
});
```

**Note:** I changed the `document.getElementById("ivancar").innerHTML = div;` code to `$("#ivancar").html(div);` for simplicity

Comment: There is no clue that he is using jquery.

Comment: `And this is my JavaScript (jQuery) code:` quote from question @Ryad.iv

Comment: The OP has the `jquery` tag, moreover `.on()` is part of `Jquery`,  And this is the plugin file `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.5.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js` ... :) anymore doubts

Comment: Ask him what's the difference -_- anyway you are right although he is creating the slider as if he does not have jquery.

Comment: I now get an error in the console: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null ** and it points to bootstrap-slider.min.js @Reddy